# VBS file to refresh external data in specific work sheets

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I want to create a .VBS file to refresh a table on a spcific worksheet.  This table's data comes from an external data source (MS query).  Usually, I just right click on the table and go to Refresh.  This is what I would like to duplicate in the .VBS file.  Is this possible?

I researched this on Stackoverflow (and Google), but I wasn't having luck finding code for the specific worksheet, just for the workbook.  I'd like to do this for the specific sheet.

I did research how to access an Excel worksheet through .VBS, and this is what I have so far:

```
Dim objXLApp, objXLWb, objXLWs

Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objXLWb = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\Test.xlsx")

Set objXLWs = objXLWb.Sheets(6)

' This is the code I added to solve my problem
For Each qry In objXLWs.QueryTables
   qry.Refresh(false)
Next
objXLWs.Calculate
' End

objXLWb.Save
objXLWb.Close (False)

Set objXLWs = Nothing   
Set objXLWb = Nothing

objXLApp.Quit
Set objXLApp = Nothing

MsgBox "Done"
```

Now, "objXLWs.Refresh" doesn't work.  Neither does RefreshAll, RefreshAllData, etc.  I get "Object does not support this property or method."  I also tried .Calculate, but it doesn't work for this case.  I am wondering if there is something that I am missing, or if I have to restructure this code a different way?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: I researched a bit more and I think I got it. I refreshed the query, then use Calculate to refresh the worksheet. After this, the sheet updated. I edited my code above with this: `code`For Each qry In objXLWs.QueryTables qry.Refresh(false) Next objXLWs.Calculate `code`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

`objXLWb.Connections("YourConnectionName").Refresh`

Comment: Did you try the suggestion that I gave?

Comment: Actually I did for another issue I was having that was separate from this one, and it worked.

Comment: Why do you think it didn't work for this one? What error did you get?